# How to have data json raw from a github url in the body of the module.exports.x lamba serverless?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have a problem whit this (file name  ***jsonRead.js***):

```
var getJSON = require("get-json");
'use strict';

module.exports.endpoint = (event, context, callback) => {
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(load()),
    };
    callback(null, response);
};
function load(){
        getJSON('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19/master/dati-json/dpc-covid19-ita-province.json', function(error, response){
            return response
        });
    }
```

when I try this and lunch from terminal `sls offline` my output is empty, but if I console.log the response of getJson I can see the JSON file from the URL.

anyone can help me? I have no idea.

my ***serverless.yml***

```
org: name
app: my-express-application-app
service: my-express-application
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
plugins:
  - serverless-offline
functions:
  loadJson:
    handler: jsonRead.endpoint
    events:
      - http:
          path: readjson
          method: get
```

Comment: Missing `return` keyword?  ...load() { **return** getJSON('http...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getJson` function returns a callback so you cannot return from this. Call the handler callback like this:

```
module.exports.endpoint = (event, context, callback) => {
  getJSON('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19/master/dati-json/dpc-covid19-ita-province.json', function(error, response){

    if(error) {
      throw new Error(error) // You can also use callback if preferred
      } else {
      callback(null, {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: response
      })
     }
   }
}
```